# Gravitation Acceleration in General of Kerr-Newman Black Hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, acceleration, kerr-newman-metric

The surface gravity (acceleration at event horizon, as measured by an observer at infinity, since the proper acceleration is infinite) of a Kerr-Newman black hole is given (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity#Kerr.E2.80.93Newman_solution)) as:$$
    \kappa = \frac{r_+ - r_-}{2 \cdot (r_+^2 + a^2)}
$$**What is the corresponding generalization of this formula for any distance from the event horizon (i.e., what's $\kappa(r)$)?**

Answer (score 0):

This would be $\rm \rm {\rm d}^2r/{\rm d}\tau^2 = \ddot{r}$, so you evaluate that for a corotating particle by solving the geodesic equation (see [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/66.html#11)) and take the limit for $\rm r \to r_{+}$ in case of the horizon, or any $\rm r$ and $\theta$ since $\rm \ddot{r}$ is not only a function of the radial but also of the poloidial coordinate.

The general equation for a black hole of charge $\rm Q$ and spin $\rm a$ for a particle with the charge $\rm q$ is in natural units and in Boyer Lindquist coordinates

$ \rm \ddot{r} =$
$\rm (a^2 \dot{\theta} \sin (2 \theta ) \ \dot{r})/(a^2 \cos ^2 \theta +r^2)+\dot{r}^2 ((r-1)/(a^2+(r-2) \ r+Q ^2)-r/(a^2 \cos ^2 \theta +r^2))+ $
$ \rm  ((a^2+(r-2) \ r+Q ^2) (8 a \sin ^2 \theta \ \dot{\phi} \ (a^2 \cos ^2 \theta \ (q \ Q -2 \dot{t})+r (2 (r-Q ^2) \dot{t}-q \ Q \ r))+ $
$\rm   8 \dot{t} \ (a^2 \cos ^2 \theta \ (\dot{t}-q \ Q )+r \ (q \ Q \ r+(Q ^2-r) \ \dot{t}))+8 r \ \dot{\theta}^2 \ (a^2 \cos ^2 \theta +r^2)^2+ $
$ \rm  \sin ^2 \theta \ \dot{\phi}^2 \ (2 a^4 \sin ^2(2 \theta )+r \ (a^2 (a^2 \cos (4 \theta )+3 a^2+4 \ (a-Q ) (a+Q ) \cos (2 \theta )+4 Q ^2)+ $ \rm
$ \rm  8 r \ (-a^2 \sin ^2 \theta +2 a^2 r \cos ^2 \theta +r^3)))))/(8 \ (a^2 \cos ^2 \theta +r^2)^3) $

so you have to set $\rm \dot{r}=\dot{\theta}=q=0, \ \dot{\phi}=|g_{t \phi}/g_{\phi \phi}|/\sqrt{|g^{t t}|}$ and $\rm \dot{t}=\sqrt{|g^{t t}|}$ to get $\rm \ddot{r}$ for a locally stationary particle with zero angular momentum (a so called ZAMO in his so called LNRF) at any given $\rm r$ and $\theta$.