# Is there an equation that is quick to use that calculates gravity around black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, black-holes

Is there an equation the can calculate gravity around black holes but is less time consuming than [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)? I want to find an equation that is simpler/faster than Einstein's Field Equations but can still accurately predict gravitation in and around black holes. Does an equation like this exist?

Comment: Since you specify accuracy, it sounds like rather than an alternative theory of gravity, you just want expressions derived from general relativity that simplify calculations for your specific use case. But what is that use case? There is not enough detail here.

Comment: The dirty secret of physical theory is that as it evolves in a way that models are based on ever more abstract "simple" principles, the mathematics becomes more intractable. This, I believe, is evidence that mathematics cannot be the substance of reality.

Comment: @JohnDoty thanks for making my (current) favourite pair of observations in one brief comment!  Also, I'd like to add, in the particular case of numerical analysis, nature does not "iterate over multidimensional grids".

Comment: If there was a simpler theory with the same predictions, don't you think we would already be using it?

Comment: @m4r35n357 Yep. Numerical methods scale very badly, but Nature has no trouble making a whole universe go.

Comment: For a Schwarzschild black hole that equation is already [simple](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/what-is-the-weight-equation-through-general-relativity), but for rotating ones the equations are a little bit more [complicated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340901/24093), so no, such an equation simpler than GR does not exist.

Comment: A realistic black hole rotates but has negligible electric charge, so should be [Kerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric). At least that's simpler than [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric).

Comment: Regarding the new question, you don't need the Einstein field equations to evaluate the effect of gravity around black holes (unless you're considering the evolution of objects of comparable mass to the black holes). Just use an already-known solution to the Einstein field equations (Schwarzschild or Kerr) and use the geodesic equation to evaluate particle trajectories.

Comment: "Gravity" is gravitational acceleration. This page describes what we observe around a black hole: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s6-07/6-07.htm

Comment: Further to my previous comment, the Kerr metric's gravitational potential is Eq. (15) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5297).

Answer (score 3):

Despite its fearsome reputation general relativity is a remarkably simple theory. One of the ways a theory can be defined is by a property called its [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)), and the [action for GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) is surprisingly simple. No simpler theory has ever been found that is consistent with experimental observations. Whether it has been *proved* that no simpler theory is possible I don't know.

So your quest is doomed to failure unless you would be happy with an approximation that holds only in limited conditions. For example there are many simplifications of GR that apply only when the gravitational fields are weak - in practice this means anywhere that isn't close to a black hole. A widely used example is [Parameterised post-Newtonian formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_post-Newtonian_formalism). However by definition these theories cannot be used in the most interesting situations e.g. black holes merging or observers falling into a black hole.

Comment: Except that it has the common defect of "remarkably simple" theories: the math is fantastically intractable in real situations.

Comment: Maybe the fearsome reputations comes from the non-linearity of the theory.

Comment: @Pipe Nonlinearity makes it harder, but even linear models scale badly in real life.

Comment: Fortunately, the extremely simple example of a body moving near to a spherical, effectively spinless, mass distribution is extremely common in the universe . Accurate GR calcs. for a black hole that depends only on mass and spin are remarkably simple compared with say accurate satellite motion around the Earth using Newtonian gravity.